# An R tidyverse way to select columns in order based on data type

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```r
 library(tidyverse)
 #> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.4.4
 #> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.4.4

 example <- tibble(
     num1 = sample(1:100, 10),
     categ1 = as.factor(c(sample(letters, 10))),
     num2 = sample(1:100, 10),
     categ2 = as.factor(c(sample(letters, 10)))
 )

 head(example)
 #> # A tibble: 6 x 4
 #>    num1 categ1  num2 categ2
 #>   <int> <fct>  <int> <fct> 
 #> 1     4 c          5 l     
 #> 2    86 u         64 b     
 #> 3    38 z         18 r     
 #> 4    95 e         44 j     
 #> 5    77 w         35 u     
 #> 6    84 y         14 i
```

Created on 2018-06-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

The above example shows a basic dataframe with integer and factor data type columns. In this small example, it is easy to use the `select(example, categ1, categ2, num1, num2)` in **dplyr** to manually pick the order you want columns to appear.

But suppose you have many columns that are a mixture of data types, and that you want all of the factors to be selected first followed by everything else (or any particular order based on data type)?

Manually typing out each column name or using `select()` helpers like `contains()` can become tedious quickly with an innumerable amount columns. I prefer a **tidyverse** solution, but would also be interested how this could be accomplished in base R.

Comment: do you have more number of classes?  try `map(list(is.factor, is.numeric), ~ example %>% select_if(.x)) %>% bind_cols`

Comment: More data types could be possible. This works and seems to allow many data types if desired. I wonder how computationally expensive this method is if you have a large data set though.

Comment: If data is big, then you could subset the first row and get the class out of it i.e. something like `example %>% slice(1) %>% map_chr(class) %>% sort %>% names %>% select(example, .)`

Comment: Clever. Thanks, akrun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example data with columns of 3 classes

```
library(tidyverse)
example <- tibble(
     num1 = as.character(sample(1:100, 10)),
     categ1 = as.factor(c(sample(letters, 10))),
     num2 = sample(1:100, 10),
     categ2 = as.factor(c(sample(letters, 10)))
 )
```

Lets say you want to order the columns in this order

```
my.order <- c('factor', 'integer', 'character')
```

i.e. factors, then integers, then characters

You can do

```
example %>% 
  select(sapply(., class) %>% .[order(match(., my.order))] %>% names)

# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    categ1 categ2  num2 num1 
#    <fct>  <fct>  <int> <chr>
#  1 y      e         94 46   
#  2 t      b         52 31   
#  3 w      c         32 57   
#  4 k      i         27 89   
#  5 n      d         76 14   
#  6 x      g         67 40   
#  7 c      v         16 20   
#  8 e      z          6 95   
#  9 i      t         70 13   
# 10 g      w         57 42
```

As a function (same output)

```
order_cols <- function(df, col.order){
  df %>% 
    select(sapply(., class) %>% .[order(match(., col.order))] %>% names)
}

example %>% 
  order_cols(c('factor', 'integer', 'character'))
```

Comment: To make it more tidyverse, may be `map_chr(., class)`

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the quick response. I like the flexibility offered here, especially in function form. I'm surprised this is not a part of **dplyr**. Maybe it is, and we have not found it yet? My main use-case was shifting factors/characters to the front so I can visually see them easily. I guess outside of that, it's not so useful? Anyway, it helps me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a **tidyverse** approach that I figured out.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.4.4
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.4.4

example <- tibble(
  num1 = sample(1:100, 10),
  categ1 = as.factor(c(sample(letters, 10))),
  num2 = sample(1:100, 10),
  categ2 = as.factor(c(sample(letters, 10)))
  )

head(example)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>    num1 categ1  num2 categ2
#>   <int> <fct>  <int> <fct> 
#> 1    33 h         94 s     
#> 2    78 x          6 k     
#> 3    82 s         84 i     
#> 4    11 k         20 o     
#> 5    51 v         11 q     
#> 6     5 w         51 b

# Use select_if() to specify data-type and pull names to insert into outter select()
# Intersect is only needed if you previously filtered 
# some columns and you do not want those factors (in this case) to creep back in 
# with the select_if() call 
example_arranged <- example %>%
  select(intersect(names(select_if(., is.factor)), names(.)), everything())

head(example_arranged)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   categ1 categ2  num1  num2
#>   <fct>  <fct>  <int> <int>
#> 1 h      s         33    94
#> 2 x      k         78     6
#> 3 s      i         82    84
#> 4 k      o         11    20
#> 5 v      q         51    11
#> 6 w      b          5    51
```

Created on 2018-06-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

```
example %>% relocate(where(is.integer), .after = where(is.factor))
```